# Why is modrewrite using my site's full path?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I wanted to redirect all non .html links to html links, such as domain.com/hey to domain.com/hey.html so I used the following rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\.html$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\+]+)$ $1\.html [R=301,L,NE]
```

However the redirect happens like this:

http://domain.com/what+there -> http://domain.com/home/user/public_html/what+there.html

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are using your `RewriteRule` in a per-directory context (`.htaccess` or `<Directory>`). [in this case](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule),

> [...] the per-directory prefix (in your case `/home/user/public_html`) is automatically removed for the `RewriteRule` pattern matching and automatically added after any relative (not starting with a slash or protocol name) substitution encounters the end of a rule set.

to avoid this, use [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase), like so:

```
RewriteBase   /
```

also note the other [*additional complexity* items](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for per-directory rewrites.

Comment: Thank you so much! I remember seeing that in mod_rewrite examples but didn't know what it did so I forgot to add it. I new to all of this.